# Automatically generate a character vector with 100 elements

Tags: r, string, vector

I would like to automatically create a vector with the following elements:

```
elements<-c("elem[1]","elem[1]" .... "elem[100]")
```

without typing elem[1], elem[2] etc by hand. How can I do this automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Try `paste0('elem[',1:100,']')`

Comment: Thanks. Can you post that as an answer so that I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: Many thanks I have added as you did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste0()`:

```
#Code
paste0('elem[',1:100,']')
```